# Creating an Exifinterface from a Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, exif

I'm trying to get a picture taken from the camera and create an Exifinterface from it to correct the orientation. The solution of this problem includes defining an Exifinterface from an Uri but I don't need to save the file in the storage so I was wondering if there is a way to do that starting from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskPhotoView).

This code

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val imageBitmap = data.extras.get("data") as Bitmap
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap)
    }
}
```

retrieve the taken picture from `data` but I'm not able to generate an Exifinterface from it. I'm using API 21 so I can't even get an Exifinterface object from an InputStream.

Answer (score 3):

EXIF tags exist in files, such as JPEG and PNG files. There are no EXIF tags in a `Bitmap`. So, there is no way to use `ExifInterface` to extract the non-existent EIXF tags from a `Bitmap`.